# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException : "Illegal char <:> at index 2" error with Kafka Connector in Mule 4 Munits

Tags: apache-kafka, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-component, mulesoft

I am facing a very tough situation running **MUnit** on my project. I am using Mule 4.3.0 and Anypoint Studio 7.4.

Apparently, the point of error is occuring while loading a **certs/cacerts** file as a property used in some **Apache Kakfa Connector TLS Configuration**.

Its working absolutely fine when running the normal Mule code (having the TLS Context).
But fails to work, when running MUnit.

I have tried many ways to get this resolved with my team, but couldn't fix it. Although similar errors been reported by other developers occasionally, I couldn't concluded that this as a `possible bug` with the `mule runtime` or especially a `Kafka Connector problem`.

> Finally, once removing the TLS context in Kafka Config, MUnit is working fine. But without TLS enabled, my project is basically useless

I need your help in resolving this and making my test work, but with TLS configurations present in its rightful place. Also, please take a look at this question in the forums: [Mule Kafka Problem](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T000054o6XESAY/illegal-char-at-index-error-with-kafka-connector)

---

Given below are the two snapshots of the Configuration used, and the error reported in the MUnit console:

### Kafka Consumer TLS Configuration Snapshot:
[image: Kafka Consumer TLS Configuration]

### Error Snapshot:

[image: Error]

Compete error report given below:

```
INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:12,077 [main] org.mule.munit.remote.container.SuiteRunDispatcher: Suite errortopic-db-test-suite.xml will not be deployed: Suite was filtered from running
INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:12,078 [munit.01] org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunnerServer: Waiting for client connection 
INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:12,086 [munit.01] org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunnerServer: Client connection received from 127.0.0.1 - true
WARN  2020-10-21 18:44:19,766 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.security.tls.TlsProperties: File tls-default.conf not found, using default configuration.
INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:19,767 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.api.tls.AbstractTlsContextFactoryBuilderFactory: Loaded TlsContextFactoryBuilderFactory implementation 'org.mule.runtime.module.tls.api.DefaultTlsContextFactoryBuilderFactory' from classloader 'java.net.URLClassLoader@7fd8c559'
INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:21,684 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising Bean: org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.ConfigurationProviderToolingAdapter-HTTP_Request_configuration_oauth
INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:21,736 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising Bean: org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.ConfigurationProviderToolingAdapter-HTTP_Request_configuration-By
WARN  2020-10-21 18:44:21,800 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.security.tls.TlsProperties: File tls-default.conf not found, using default configuration.
INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:21,802 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising Bean: org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.ConfigurationProviderToolingAdapter-Apache_Kafka_Consumer_configuration
WARN  2020-10-21 18:44:21,810 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.security.tls.TlsProperties: File tls-default.conf not found, using default configuration.
INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:21,872 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising Bean: org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.ConfigurationProviderToolingAdapter-Apache_Kafka_Producer_configuration
WARN  2020-10-21 18:44:21,879 [munit.01] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.security.tls.TlsProperties: File tls-default.conf not found, using default configuration.
INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:21,917 [munit.01] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig: ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [hiding intentional]
    buffer.memory = 1024000
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class com.mulesoft.connectors.kafka.internal.model.serializer.InputStreamSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 1
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = SunJSSE
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = \C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/munit-temp-dir/munitworkingdir5345007588634892776/container/apps/app/cacerts
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = jks
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class com.mulesoft.connectors.kafka.internal.model.serializer.InputStreamSerializer

INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:21,985 [munit.01] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin: Successfully logged in.
INFO  2020-10-21 18:44:21,996 [munit.01] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: The consumer has an invalid configuration
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: The consumer has an invalid configuration
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:434)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:298)
    at com.mulesoft.connectors.kafka.internal.connection.provider.ProducerConnectionProvider.initialise(ProducerConnectionProvider.java:437)
    at com.mulesoft.connectors.kafka.internal.connection.provider.KafkaConnectionProvider.initialise(KafkaConnectionProvider.java:129)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:56)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:117)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.AbstractConnectionProviderWrapper.initialise(AbstractConnectionProviderWrapper.java:113)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.ClassLoaderConnectionProviderWrapper.initialise(ClassLoaderConnectionProviderWrapper.java:96)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:56)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:117)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.AbstractConnectionProviderWrapper.initialise(AbstractConnectionProviderWrapper.java:113)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:56)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:117)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.AbstractConnectionProviderWrapper.initialise(AbstractConnectionProviderWrapper.java:113)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:56)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:117)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.LifecycleAwareConfigurationInstance.doInitialise(LifecycleAwareConfigurationInstance.java:297)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.LifecycleAwareConfigurationInstance.initialise(LifecycleAwareConfigurationInstance.java:145)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:56)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:117)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.LifecycleAwareConfigurationProvider.lambda$null$0(LifecycleAwareConfigurationProvider.java:83)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:132)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(DefaultLifecycleManager.java:46)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.LifecycleAwareConfigurationProvider.lambda$initialise$1(LifecycleAwareConfigurationProvider.java:81)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:224)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:966)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.LifecycleAwareConfigurationProvider.initialise(LifecycleAwareConfigurationProvider.java:80)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:56)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedConsumer.accept(CheckedConsumer.java:19)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:115)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:73)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringRegistryLifecycleManager$SpringContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(SpringRegistryLifecycleManager.java:128)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:175)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.applyPhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:146)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringRegistry.applyLifecycle(SpringRegistry.java:289)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.applyLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:339)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.initializeComponents(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:287)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.lambda$applyLifecycle$4(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:250)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.context.DefaultMuleContext.withLifecycleLock(DefaultMuleContext.java:531)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.applyLifecycle(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:248)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.initializeComponents(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:329)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.initializeComponents(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:317)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.config.TestComponentLocator.initializeComponents(TestComponentLocator.java:63)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.model.builders.SuiteBuilder.build(SuiteBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunMessageHandler.buildSuite(RunMessageHandler.java:108)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunMessageHandler.parseSuiteMessage(RunMessageHandler.java:94)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunMessageHandler.parseAndRun(RunMessageHandler.java:81)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunMessageHandler.handle(RunMessageHandler.java:75)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunnerServer.handleClientMessage(RunnerServer.java:145)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunnerServer.run(RunnerServer.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: \C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/munit-temp-dir/munitworkingdir5345007588634892776/container/apps/app/cacerts
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:172)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:157)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:442)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:423)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: \C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/munit-temp-dir/munitworkingdir5345007588634892776/container/apps/app/cacerts
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder$SecurityStore.lastModifiedMs(SslEngineBuilder.java:298)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder$SecurityStore.<init>(SslEngineBuilder.java:275)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.createTruststore(SslEngineBuilder.java:182)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.<init>(SslEngineBuilder.java:100)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:168)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: Mule 4.3.1 has not been released. I changed it to 4.3.0. Feel free to correct if that is not the right version.

Comment: What is the value of `${secure:tls.truststore.path}`?

Comment: Thanks for the version edit ! The property value is `tls.truststore.path=cacerts`

Comment: Where does the path `\C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/munit-temp-dir/munitworkingdir5345007588634892776/container/apps/app/cacerts` come from then? The only value in the screenshot is `certs/${secure:tls.truststore.path}`. That doesn't add up.

Comment: That is exactly what even we couldn't figure out. It looks like this other path is being auto generated by taking the cacerts file provided, and load it into munit-temp-dir for its own execution. This munit-temp-dir is getting auto generated every time, even when we manually delete it before test runs. I think you will observe the same if you run any munits you may have with you.

Comment: That path starting with c:/users is declared nowhere. It's a thing which Munit auto builds, similar to target folder build for normal mule code runs. Remember if I comment or remove this TLS(Security) configuration from the main xml. and rerun munits, then munits are working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223497/discussion-between-thinker-101-and-aled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been identified as a bug with the Anypoint Studio.
MuleSoft Support has suggested the below.

1. Upgrade the studio version to the latest patch **4.3.0-20200925** which has all the fixes included.

> The patches are cumulative so all fixes from the august release will be available in the latest too.

2. The distributions are stored in the [Mulesoft Nexus EE Repo](https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/com/mulesoft/mule/distributions/mule-runtime-impl-bom/4.3.0-20200925/) repo so you will need to ensure you have the credentials configured in your `settings.xml`.
3. Follow this documentation [Patching](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/2.3/runtime-patching), which explains how to patch MUNITS using maven or studio.

Note: The first time execution may take a while because the Runtime artifacts will be downloaded to your local repo.